# Where can I find the login attempts for Squirrelmail?

Tags: log-files, login, squirrelmail

I have a Squirrelmail + Exim4 mail server running Ubuntu; Squirrelmail is configured to use the user accounts already on the box as the username/password combinations (LDAP). I was wondering how/where I could view the Squirrelmail login attempts?

Answer (score 1):

Install the [Squirrel Logger](http://squirrelmail.org/plugin_view.php?id=52) plug-in, and specify the log file, and what you want logged. Make sure you [configure the config.php](http://debsvn.jhr-online.de/squirrelmail-logger/trunk/README) file before [enabling the plug-in](http://squirrelmail.org/docs/admin/admin-7.html).

By default, Squirrel Mail has no logs of it's own, you'd have to read/interpret the IMAP and LDAP logs. Installing this quick plug-in allows Squirrel Mail to write a log of it's own, and you can configure what gets logged there. Don't forget to add the log to your log rotation program so it doesn't take over the disk.

Answer (score 0):

In the IMAP server log: look for connections from 127.0.0.1